# ExtJs select component by id starting with a string

Tags: extjs

i need to create a component dynamically by a button click. My restrictions are:

1. It's going to has an Id starts with a fixed string like 'myComp_' and followed by a random number
2. At any time there will be only one component that has an id starts with 'myComp_xxx'

So before creating the component i have to check if there's any created before and remove it... My problem starts here. Ext.getCmp() wants the specific id. But i only have that fixed string : myComp_...

Is there any way to get the component created before???

Thanks in advance and sorry about my English.

Answer (score 8):

For ExtJs 4.X use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('*[id^=myComp_xxx]');`

For ExtJs 3.X you can either use the following

```
var el = Ext.query('*[id^=myComp_xxx]');
var cmp = Ext.getCmp(el.id);
```

Or (this one i haven't tried personally, but i think it should work) if the component is a child of a component that you can access, then:

`var el = parentComp.find("action","btn");`

and set a property called `action : btn` in the button config.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are looking for is [DomQuery](http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/docs/output/Ext.DomQuery.html).

Ex:

```
Ext.query("*[id^=myComp_xxx]")
```

Comment: I tried but that gives me dom element. Not the component. Can i get the component from here?

Comment: I think `Ext.get(dom_element)` will give you the component

Comment: Actually, no. [`Ext.get()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-get) returns DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this: [Ext.getCmp(id)](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp)

```
Ext.getCmp("myComp_xxx");
```

Comment: i believe i was not so clear at the question. that 'xxx' part is unknown. It's a random number..

Comment: But why don't you just give the component your random ID? If it only is displayed once?
Your not obligated to let ExtJS handle ID generation.

Comment: Are you telling me that i should get rid of the random part and create the component with a specific id?

Comment: Yes, that's indeed what I'm trying to tell you. Or you can fill up another property and query your component. If it's inside a panel you could query like this: panel.down('field[name=myName]');

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should be using the normal component query stuff - in general it is not a good idea to use id.  You can query by xtype and by itemId (which you can assign manually).

The following

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid form');
```

would find all things with xtype grid that have forms inside them somewhere.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid #okButton');
```

whereas the # here is saying look for grids that have something with itemId 'okButton' in them.

You can nest this to whatever level you need and use other operators to be more specific and as someone else has rightly pointed out you can use up and down on components to do this relative to the current component.  Its worth noting that rather than getting an array back with all the results you just get the first one when you use up and down.

See [the documentation](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.ComponentQuery.html) for more information this.

Also see point 6 on this [list of bad practices](http://www.sencha.com/blog/top-10-ext-js-development-practices-to-avoid) to avoid for more of the why

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if you know 'where' your component is going to be created is to use the `up()/down()` methods.

E.g. if you have a button and want to get the form it's contained within inside a click handler you can do something like this:

```
function myClickHandler(btn) {
     var form = btn.up('form');

     //do something with form 
}
```